# How to get INDEX of word inside a string

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to get the INDEX of a word inside a string and if possible also to delete all the characters previous to this word in the string, it would make my life easier.

Could anyone help me? Im doing this on c#

Comment: can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll want to use the IndexOf function on a string. This will tell you the starting character position of the word, character, etc that you're looking for.

Here is an example console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String testing = "text that i am looking for";
        Console.Write(testing.IndexOf("looking") + Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine(testing.Substring(testing.IndexOf("looking")));

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

This will output: 
15
looking for

Comment: Just too add,  it's best to check `testing.IndexOf` is greater than `-1` before using it, otherwise `Substring` will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception if `looking` isn't found in the string.

Comment: Good call - I wrote this under the assumption that there would be more data validation prior to the actual use.

Comment: AWESOME! THANKS!, did not know about substring :p

Comment: @TravisSharp - That's fine, the answer was just to give an example (+1). Thought I'd just append that for anyone in case they weren't aware :)

Comment: What if we have more than one 'looking' in the string. For example, in the sentence: "I am looking for looking in the string". I want to get only the index of the first 'looking' in the sentence. What`s the solution?!

Comment: @Pedram indexOf will return the first occurence. If you need all occurences then you should use a regex to find all matches.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use Substring to delete all the characters previous

```
string str = "I'm stuck here please help, something else....yyyy";
string output = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("help"));
WriteLine($"Output string value  :{output}");//help,something else....yyyy
```